# In my python django projuct tried to host in godaddy cpanel but the pillow is not installing

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, cpanel

```
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/libImaging/XbmEncode.c:16:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/libImaging/ZipDecode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ZipDecode.o
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/libImaging/ZipDecode.c:18:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/libImaging/ZipEncode.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ZipEncode.o
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/libImaging/ZipEncode.c:17:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/libImaging/codec_fd.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/codec_fd.o
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/libImaging/codec_fd.c:2:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/map.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/map.o
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/map.c:23:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/outline.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/outline.o
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/outline.c:22:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"10.0.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include -I/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/include -I/opt/alt/python39/include/python3.9 -c src/path.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/path.o
  In file included from src/libImaging/Imaging.h:688,
                   from src/path.c:29:
  src/libImaging/ImagingUtils.h:35: warning: 'inline' is not at beginning of declaration
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-result"
  gcc -shared -L/opt/alt/openssl/lib64 -L/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/opt/alt/python39/lib64,-rpath=/opt/alt/openssl/lib64 -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-v -L/opt/alt/sqlite/usr/lib64 -L/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=/opt/alt/sqlite/usr/lib64 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -ffat-lto-objects -flto-partition=none -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/decode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/encode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/BcnDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/BoxBlur.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ColorLUT.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantPngQuant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Reduce.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/SgiRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/TgaRleEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/codec_fd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/map.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/outline.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/path.o -L/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/tcl8.5/tclx8.4 -L/usr/lib64/atlas -L/usr/lib64/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysqlclient -L/usr/lib64/mysqlclient-compat -L/usr/lib64/tcl8.5 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib -L/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -lxcb -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  collect2 version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (x86-64 Linux/ELF)
  /usr/bin/ld --eh-frame-hdr --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu -shared -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtbeginS.o -L/opt/alt/openssl/lib64 -L/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -L/opt/alt/sqlite/usr/lib64 -L/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -L/home/xhpnfadbs797/virtualenv/public_html/shopwithambro.com/3.9/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/tcl8.5/tclx8.4 -L/usr/lib64/atlas -L/usr/lib64/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysqlclient -L/usr/lib64/mysqlclient-compat -L/usr/lib64/tcl8.5 -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib -L/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../.. -rpath=/opt/alt/python39/lib64 -rpath=/opt/alt/openssl/lib64 --enable-new-dtags -v -rpath=/opt/alt/sqlite/usr/lib64 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/_imaging.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/decode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/display.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/encode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Access.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/AlphaComposite.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Bands.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/BcnDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/BitDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Blend.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/BoxBlur.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Chops.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ColorLUT.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Convert.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ConvertYCbCr.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Copy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Crop.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Dib.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Draw.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Effects.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/EpsEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/File.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Fill.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Filter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/FliDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Geometry.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/GetBBox.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/GifDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/GifEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/HexDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Histo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Jpeg2KDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Jpeg2KEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/JpegDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/JpegEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Matrix.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ModeFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Negative.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Offset.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Pack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PackDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Palette.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Paste.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PcdDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PcxDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/PcxEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Point.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Quant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantHash.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantHeap.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantOctree.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/QuantPngQuant.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/RankFilter.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/RawDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/RawEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Reduce.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Resample.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/SgiRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Storage.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/SunRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/TgaRleDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/TgaRleEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/TiffDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/Unpack.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/UnpackYCC.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/UnsharpMask.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/XbmDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/XbmEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ZipDecode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/ZipEncode.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/libImaging/codec_fd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/map.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/outline.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/path.o -ljpeg -lz -ltiff -lxcb -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lpthread -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
  GNU ld version 2.20.51.0.2-5.48.1.el6.tuxcare.els4 20100205
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

iam trying to hosting my python django project in cpanel

but in that the pillow is not installing

Comment: What command or code did you run to get this output?